# Error implementing Server side rendering of react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I have created an application in react. I am trying server-side rendering of it. I followed a youtube video and followed all the setps. I did with express js. But now when m running my app. I am getting this error
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: delete ```package-lock``` file, reinstall all dependencies with ```npm install``` or ```yarn add``` and try running again

Comment: Thanks..I tried but it dint help